# Ethernet USB adapter discard settings

Tags: macos, network, usb, performance, ethernet

I use Mac Mini Apple M1 2020 with macOS 13.4.1.
I have new 1Gbps internet provider and i tried to test speed. My result is only 100Mbps.

In my Mikrotik router:

```
                    name: ether1     ether2     
                  status: link-ok    link-ok    
        auto-negotiation: done       done       
                    rate: 1Gbps      100Mbps    
             full-duplex: yes        yes        
         tx-flow-control: no         yes        
         rx-flow-control: no         yes        
             advertising: 10M-half   10M-half   
                          10M-full   10M-full   
                          100M-half  100M-half  
                          100M-full  100M-full  
                          1000M-half 1000M-half 
                          1000M-full 1000M-full 
link-partner-advertising: 10M-half   10M-half   
                          10M-full   10M-full   
                          100M-half  100M-half  
                          100M-full  100M-full  
                          1000M-full
```

I tried to change the USB 10/100/1000 LAN settings:
Hardware -> Speed -> 1000baseT
Full duplex and 1500MTU.

After I pressed th OK button the changes not saved. The setting of the adapter go back auto (100Mbps)

I tried to change advertising value in router only 1000M-half and 1000M-full but my adapter don't connect.
The cable tested and OK.
The USB is a Realtek chip and I installed the realtek driver.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

I found my problem. The cable was wrong, becouse the wire pairs color order was not correct.

Thank you for your helps!
BR,
Att

Answer (score 0):

What USB ethernet adapter are you using? USB2 adapters usually clock out at 100Mb/s. USB2 has a maximum speed of 480Mb/s so the ethernet adapter will will have to use a speed lower than that such as 100 or 10Mb/s.

Can you also check the cable between the two devices? Not all ethernet cable is the same and some cables have only 4 pairs of wires on the inside. 4 pairs will only be able to carry data at 100Mb/s.

Pictured below is a grey cable with 4 pairs (4 coloured and 4 striped) on the left. On the right is a yellow cable with 2 pairs (you can see orange and green pairs but no blue and brown).

[image]

I would recommend leaving the settings on the default as the two devices will usually be able to negotiate the connection details better than us humans. (I have on several occasions edited settings only to forget about them and get stuck with weird ethernet issues)

Comment: I checked this, all wire is used to connection.

Comment: I just thought of a second reason and updated my answer. Are you by chance using a USB 2 adapter? Let me know what model of USB to ethernet adapter is so we can check.

Comment: Hi, I tried other USB C type RJ45 adapter and same....

Comment: Do you have a model of the USB C adapter? What about the built in ethernet port on the Mac mini? Is there a reason you're using an external ethernet port?

Comment: Yes, I use it to connect an other network, but good idea!
I tried to change two interfaces, and absolutelly same, the speed only 100M.

Answer (score 0):

You likely have an issue with your switch or the connection to the switch (cable).

Both Ethernet devices are advertising that they're capable of 1000M-full (1Gbps Full Duplex) connections.  However, the *link partner* (switch) is not advertising this speed for `ether2`; it's giving your a 100M-full advertisement.

This likely means that the switch port isn't 1Gbps capable.  You might have a switch with a limited number of Gbit ports (likely a single uplink port) and the rest are 10/100Mbit.

Try swapping the ports your cables are connected to and see if the problem goes away.

Comment: `ether2` is my mac mini USB C ethernet adapter connection.
The cable is new and I tested it with cable tester. I'ts ok.
The router is new Mikrotik RB750Gr3 with latest 6.48.6 rOS.

Comment: Ok.... It still doesn't change what the *link partner* is advertising as a capability.  The issue could be the port, the cable or the adapter.  This is why I said to swap ports.  You know that everything works with `ether1`.  If the problem moves when you change ports, you've isolated the problem.